# MetalPerformanceShaders MTLCommandBuffer run parallel

Tags: metal

I have encoded 100 commands in the MTLCommandBuffer and they are processed one by one as understand in one thread.

```
for i in 0..<50 {
    filter1.encode(...)
    filter2.encode(...) // use result of the filter1
}

commandBuffer.commit()
commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
```

but is there is way to run it in 50 threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the sorts of tasks you perform on a GPU are already highly parallelized. If it's not parallelizable, then doing it on a GPU is probably not appropriate. For example, when doing image processing, the work for each pixel will be done in parallel with the work for a bunch of other pixels. Attempting to work on two images simultaneously would not generally allow the work to finish faster (unless the images are trivially small).

Also, Metal may not necessarily execute commands serially. It must produce results *as if* they were executed serially, but if it can determine that two commands are independent (e.g. they don't touch the same resources), it's allowed to run them in parallel, assuming the GPU has the spare capacity.

Comment: it seems that you are right and Metal does the "magic" in this case
I've tried to explicitly split data into 8 threads with DispatchGroup() and did get exact same results

Comment: Using GCD will only encode the workload to the command buffer in parallel. It won’t make the workload actually run on the GPU any more in parallel than it otherwise would have.